# Regex Splitting Until a digit is reached

Tags: c#, regex

I have a batch of order codes

```
MMY7570799 
QW123234 
RTY12312212
```

Each will either have between a one and three character prefix, followed by a number.

How do I do a split so I get the characters and the numbers for any occurrence using regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following pattern would capture the characters in the the first group and the digits in the second:

```
^([A-Z]{1,3})(\d+)$
```

You can see it in action here: http://regexr.com?2vh9c

Comment: winner!  cheers buddy.  I didn't know about the tool.. that's goinmg to save me laods of time in the future !

Comment: That page is fantastic. You might also have a look at a reference page: http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html which also comes in handy at times :)

Answer (score 5):

This regex will give you 2 named capture groups (`code` & `number`) containing what you want:

```
(?<code>[A-Za-z]{1,3})(?<number>\d+)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `Regex.Split()`

```
String s = "MMY7570799";
String[] Result = Regex.Split(s, @"(?<=\P{N})(?=\p{N})");
```

This splits when there is not a digit (`\P{N}`) on the left (`(?<=\P{N})`) and a digit (`\p{N}`) on the right (`(?=\p{N})`)

`\p{N}` or `\p{Number}`: any kind of numeric character in any script. See [regular-expression.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop)

`\P{N}` is NOT `\p{N}`

Answer (score 0):

Well you can try your hand at LINQ in case its consistent that a group of characters would be then followed by numbers.

```
string original = "MMY7570799";
string characters = new string(s.TakeWhile(c => char.IsLetter(c)).ToArray());
string nums = original.Replace(characters, "");
```